# Percentiles in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, statistics, percentile

I have the following query, in which I'm attempting to work out percentiles for the days between a letter being sent and today's date:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUM(TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
            ( TO_DATE( SUBSTR(M.LETTER_SENT, 1, 11), 'YYYY-MON-DD') )) ASC) AS PERCENTILE_10,
   PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUM(TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
            ( TO_DATE( SUBSTR(M.LETTER_SENT, 1, 11), 'YYYY-MON-DD') )) ASC) AS PERCENTILE_90
FROM MV_TABLE M8
WHERE M8.LETTER_SENT != 'N'
GROUP BY M8.LETTER_SENT;
```

I am perhaps wrong in thinking that, it should return the 10th and 90th percentile for the result set?

`M.LETTER_SENT` is in the format `YYYY-MON-DD: USER_ID`. So my query uses `SYSDATE` - `TO_DATE(SUBSTR(M.LETTER_SENT,1, 11), 'YYYY-MON-DD')` to work out the number of days between.
So the `M.LETTER_SENT` actual value for the result set I list below of 4 days `2015-Feb-27: rstone`

That query returns the following result set:

```
242
4
4
4
39
11
18
361
```

My understanding of percentiles is that if you want the 90th percentile the following occurs.

```
number of records * percentile = percentile => (round up) = index value
```

So in my situation it's:

```
8 * 0.1 = 0.8 => (round up) = 1

8 * 0.9 = 7.2 => (round up) = 8
```

The 1st value on the ordered result set is: 4
The 8th value on the ordered result set is: 361

Oracle for me returns: 11 as the 10th percentile though?

When I do 0.2 + 0.8 percentiles I get 12, 242 respectively. I always understood there to be a few different ways to calculate percentiles. So how does Oracle calculate these results am I wrong in my thoughts of what the percentiles should be?

Comment: Why do you have `ORDER BY SUM()`? I think that will do an accumulated sum. Perhaps if you provide the actual values of `LETTER_SENT` we could help more.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp `M.LETTER_SENT` is in the format `YYYY-MON-DD: USER_ID`. That's all I have regarding the letter date, I use `SYSDATE` - `M.LETTER_SENT` to get the number of days since the letter was sent.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp added to Q